# SAS : Specifying informat length vs. column input

Tags: sas

I have the following program that works fine :

```
data test ; 
infile datalines ; 
input emp_id 3. @4 height 2.  @6 weight 3. ; 
datalines ; 
00168155
00270200
00362102
00474180
;
run;
proc print;
run;
```

---

However the following program writes`null` values for `emp_id` to the test dataset, I have no idea why

```
data test ; 
infile datalines ; 
input @12 type @ ; 
if type=1 then input emp_id 3. @4 height 2.  @6 weight 3. ;  /* 1-3 instead of 3. fixes the issue */
else if type=2 then input emp_id 3. @5 height 2. @8   weight 3. ; /* 1-3 instead of 3. fixes the issue */
datalines ; 
00168155   1
002 70 200 2
00362102   1
004 74 180 2
;
run;
proc print ;
run ;
```

I am using the same `3.` informat  as in the fist case but emp_id is not read correctly . Why ?

---

**I dont understand why informat `3.` works perfect in the first case but not in the second case . I know the fix , I simply have to  use `1-3` column input pointer .**

instead of `if type=1 then input emp_id 3. @4 height 2.  @6 weight 3. ;`

need to use `if type=1 then input emp_id 1-3 @4 height 2.  @6 weight 3. ;`

**Why**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you used the input statement to read the type, the pointer moved to a postion after @type and it will try to read the emp_id after the type. Add @1 between the input and emp_id like `input @1 emp_id 3.` and it will read the emp_id at the first position.

To experiment change your datalines to the following. You will see that the emp_id will be 99x if you don't add the @1.

```
datalines ; 
00168155   1 991
002 70 200 2 992
00362102   1 993
004 74 180 2 994
;
```